# I am creating String by using String(char) but getting optional value with that, how to remove it?

Tags: ios, swift

my output is coming like "Optional(\"A\") but I want only string "A". I have to apply filter on my array by using this character.

```
let char  = selectedSection.characters.last
let str = String(char)
let array = result?.objectForKey("GetClassPeriodList") as! NSArray
let filtered = array.filter {
    return ($0["Section_Code"] as! String) == str
}
print(filtered)
```

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: Search How to unwrap optionals in Swift.

Comment: try by adding ! or ? at the end your string object

Comment: yes tried by adding !

Comment: The `last` property returns an *optional*.

Comment: ok any replacement code for this or how I can remove optional

Comment: Do you know what optionals are in Swift?

Comment: yes I know but still I am new to swift, if we can unwrap that value it should remove the optional from string

Comment: replace as let char  = selectedSection.characters.last! or look at 
pbodsk's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @martin-r says, `last` gives you an optional because you can not be certain that when you ask for the last character of a collection, you actually end out with a character, what if the collection was empty for instance?

What you can do is unwrap it using `if let`, so you could write:

```
if let char  = selectedSection.characters.last {
    let str = String(char)
    let array = result?.objectForKey("GetClassPeriodList") as! NSArray
    let filtered = array.filter {
        return ($0["Section_Code"] as! String) == str
    }
    print(filtered)
}
```

And then you know for certain that your `char` contains a value which you can continue to work with.

You can read more about optionals [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html)

Hope that helps you.

Comment: You can use force unwrapping using ! but it is not recomended unless you're sure that the optional you're unwrapping contains a value. If in case it doesn't contain value you'll be encountering a run time error. The same applies for type casting, If you're sure use as! if not use if let along with as? for typecasting.

Comment: @sukhmeet you can, but using `!` can be dangerous. What if your `selectedSection` is empty and you ask for the last element? What will you get in return? Try this in a playground for instance: `var badString: String = ""
let last = badString.characters.last!`, if I do that, I am rewarded with EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) which is the compilers way of telling you that it encountered nil and has lost all hope and given up. Therefore it is almost always better to unwrap your optionals using `if let` or `guard` statements.

Comment: And yes, as @iamyogish says, if you know for sure that your optional is not nil (i.e. you've checked it...`if selectedSection != nil`) then it is safe to use `!`